# Schengen Type C visa overlapping with Type D visa

Tags: schengen

I already have schengen type D visa for Poland for one year expiring in November 2018. However, due to change in circumstances, I have not travelled to Poland and like to visit Italy for one week for holidays in April 2018. Is it possible to apply for overlapping type C visa for Italy even though I have type D visa?